# Apache Tiles Path Root

Tags: java, tiles2

I am using Tiles 2 and I want to have an attribute that sets the root path for resources. I have this is my XML:

```
<definition name="titledWrapper" template="/WEB-INF/templates/titledWrapper.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="includes" value="/WEB-INF/templates/includes.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="navigation" value="/WEB-INF/templates/navigation.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="pathRoot" value="./" type="string" />
</definition>
```

This is a base definition that I will extend other pages from. In the 'titledWrapper.jsp' page, I have this:

```
<img src="<tiles:getAsString name="pathRoot" />statics/images/corner.gif" />
```

I am also importing the Tiles tag lib. Other uses of `getAsString` work, though they are not in an attribute like this. When I load the page, my image source is literally `<tiles:getAsString name="`. What do I need to do differently to fix this?

Comment: escape the "" around pathRoot

Comment: `<img src="<tiles:getAsString name=\"pathRoot\" />statics/images/corner.gif" />` results in HTTP 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use ' ' instead of " ".

Comment: Tried `<img src="<tiles:getAsString name='pathRoot' />statics/images/corner.gif" />` with no change.

Comment: first try to see the pathroot in the title... example     <title><tiles:getAsString name="pathRoot"/></title> this work???

Comment: and try remove this type="string" on XML

Comment: It looks like the problem is something else entirely. I'll give you credit for getting me on the right path.